# Pass functions output as another functions argument in designed format

Tags: python, scripting

I have the below function that I store the output into a variable called `post`.

```py
jobs = ('Cook', 'Vet', 'Doctor', 'Pilot')
def careers():
    output_of_careers = "Heres a list of jobs\n\n"
    for j in jobs:
        output_of_careers += f"This person is a {j}.\n"
    output_of_careers += "\nAre you interested in any of these as careers?"
    return output_of_careers
post = careers()
```

I need to pass this into another function called (for example) `apicall`

```
apicall(argument1,argument2,post)
```

What ends up happening is I get `None` as a response for the `post` argument in the function, even if I use `print(post)` or `print(careers())`.

What I need is to have `post` display the below output printed of the function `careers()`

```
Heres a list of jobs

This person is a Cook.
This person is a Vet.
This person is a Doctor.
This person is a Pilot.

Are you interested in any of these as careers?
```

What would be the correct way to accomplish this in Python? Thank you

Editing to add `apicall()` function for reference

```
def apicall(arugment1,arugment2,post):
    apikey = 'Key here'
    headers = {'X-API-Key' : apikey}
    uri = 'urihere'
    
    # Set Query
    query = 'mutation {windowUpdate(guid: "' + arugment1 + '", window: {id: "' + arugment2 +'", configuration: {combobox: {text: "' + str(post) + '"}}, {errors {description}}}'


    response = requests.post(uri, headers = headers, data=query)
    print(response)
```

Comment: Can you specify where the `apicall` function is being called?

Comment: You have to pass `jobs` in the function so that it can be used in the loop

Comment: I think you should add `print(query)` just before `requests.post()` to see what the final query looks like.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham I have added the function for reference.  I need the post argument in apicall function to display the output of the function careers() in the printed format above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems pretty much correct, except you might want to pass the `jobs` argument into `careers()`, so that the output of that function can change based on the jobs you pass it.

```
jobs = ('Cook', 'Vet', 'Doctor', 'Pilot')

def careers(jobs):
    output_of_careers = ""
    output_of_careers += output_of_careers +"Heres a list of jobs\n\n"
    for j in jobs:
        output_of_careers = output_of_careers +"This person is a " + j + ".\n"
    
    output_of_careers = output_of_careers +"\nAre you interested in any of these as careers?"
    return output_of_careers

post = careers(jobs)

def apicall(argument1, argument2, post_argument):
    print(post_argument)

apicall(post)
# Output:
# Heres a list of jobs
#
# This person is a Cook.
# This person is a Vet.
# This person is a Doctor.
# This person is a Pilot.
# 
# Are you interested in any of these as careers?
```

If your `apicall` function is returning a response with nothing in it, it's most likely that you're not posting the right data to the API. We will have to see the function to determine what's going wrong there.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I added apicall() function for reference. I need to display the output of the function careers()

Comment: Thanks for updating it, could you show us the status code and response of the apicall? Also, if you `print(query)` 1 line above `response = requests.post(....)` , do you get the output you expected to send to the API?

Comment: So when I printed out query is when I found the issue. The query was exactly the way I wanted but apparently the text needed to be triple wrapped in parenthesis in order for GraphQL to pick it up. Thank you for your help on this.